# AngularJs within multiple iframes on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe

If a web page contains multiple `iframe`s,
and each of them contains an angular app (all of the same version):

- Is there a way to make Angular be loaded just once, and be reused by all of the apps in each `iframe`?

  - i.e. share `window.angular`
- What implications are there, if the main page itself is an angular app?
- What complications can occur when these `iframe`s being served from a different domain than the main page?